# Typescript Tagged Unions - Can the compiler warn you about missed branch cases?

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I'm new to TypeScript.  I've got the following code:

```
type Circle = { kind: "circle" }
type Rectangle = { kind: "rectangle" }
type Triangle = { kind: "triangle" }
type Shape = Circle | Rectangle | Triangle

function numberOfSides(shape: Shape) {
    switch (shape.kind) {
        case "circle": return 0;
    }
}
```

Currently this compiles fine.  Is there any configuration or option so the compiler can warn me that I'm missing cases in my switch statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you just need two things - 1. turn on `strictNullChecks` or `noImplicitReturns`.  2. Mark `numberOfSides`' return type as `Number`.  At that point the compiler will catch that you are not dealing with all the cases and give you this error:

> Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.

Comment: Thanks so much.  You pointed me in the right direction.  I found out about tsconfig compilerOptions.  Your way works, but I also set noImplicitReturns options, and that seems to work as well.  Maybe you could update your answer with that as another option?